# Hadoop, Launched reduce tasks = 1

Tags: hadoop, reduce

Hadoop is running on a cluster of 8 nodes. The submitted job produces several key-value objects as mapper output with different keys (manually checked), so I except to have several launched reducers to manage the data in the nodes.

I don't know why, as the log report, the number of launched reduce tasks is **always** 1. Since there are tens different keys I expect to have at least as many reducers as the number of nodes, i.e. 8 (which is also the number of slaves).

This is the log when job ends

```
13/05/25 04:02:31 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201305242051_0051
13/05/25 04:02:31 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 30
13/05/25 04:02:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
13/05/25 04:02:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=1
13/05/25 04:02:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=21415994
13/05/25 04:02:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
13/05/25 04:02:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
13/05/25 04:02:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Rack-local map tasks=7
13/05/25 04:02:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=33
13/05/25 04:02:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=26
13/05/25 04:02:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=5486645
13/05/25 04:02:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Output Format Counters 
13/05/25 04:02:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Written=2798
13/05/25 04:02:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
13/05/25 04:02:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=2299685944
13/05/25 04:02:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_READ=2170126861
13/05/25 04:02:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=2879025663
13/05/25 04:02:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN=2798
13/05/25 04:02:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Input Format Counters 
13/05/25 04:02:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Read=2170123000
```

Other (useful?) information:

- for each node I have 1 core assigned to the job
- I manually checked that the job is effectively running on 8 nodes.
- There is no parameter set by me for setting the reducers tasks fixed to one
- Hadoop version: 1.1.2

So, do you have any idea of why the reducer number is 1? and not more?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should:

1. firstly checkout whether  your cluster support more than 1 reducer
2. Specify the reduce members you want to run

### checkout the supported reducer count

The most convienient way to checkout it out is using the `jobtracker` webUI:  `http://localhost:50030/machines.jsp?type=active` ( you may need to  remove `localhost` with the hostname that the jobtracker is running. It will show all the active TaskTrackers in your cluster, and how many reducers each TaskTracker could run concurrently.

### Specify the reducer number

There are three ways for you:

#### Specify the reducer number in your code

Like zsxwing have showed out, you should specify the reducer number by calls `setNumReduceTasks()` method of `JobConf`. And give the reduce number as the parameter.

#### Specify the reducer number in your command line

you could also pass the reducer number in command line like the following:
`bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.0.4.jar  terasort -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=2 teragen teragen_out`.

The above command line will start 2 reducers.

#### Specify the reducer number in  your `conf/mapred-site.xml`

You can also add a new property in your mapred-site.xml like this:

```
  <property>
    <name>mapred.reduce.tasks</name>
    <value>2</value>
  </property>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the reducer number by yourself (default is 1) no matter how many keys outputed by mappers. You can use `job.setNumReduceTasks(5)` to set the reduce tasks 5.